# Proposed Method To Curb "Tool Recommendation" Questions - Change "Tools" tag to "Using Tools"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've spent a considerable amount of time searching for information on tag naming strategies, meta tags, and other best practices for creating tags on a Stack Exchange site, and I've found nothing on using verbs as tag names.

On [Project Management Stack Exchange](http://pm.stackexchange.com), we've had problems with tool recommendation questions and have recently listed them in our FAQ as off-topic. We've cleaned up questions in our "Tools" tag and have come up with a possible new tag to narrow the focus on tools questions to just how to use them.

One of our users proposed the "Using Tools" tag. Since I've not seen any examples of verbs as tag names, I wanted to get a more wide opinion on whether this is a good tag name, as well as what the potential disadvantages might be of using such a tag.

The "Using Tools" tag would explicitly disallow the majority of tool recommendation questions and we hope would make it clear that this tag is not intended for recommendations. (Well detailed questions that border on tool recommendations may still have a place on our site, but the majority are not healthy questions)

Lastly, I'm also asking this question here instead of our Meta PMSE site since this reaches out to a larger crowd, and since other sites with tool recommendation problems may benefit from the responses.

So, why would this be a good tag?  Why would it be bad?

Answer (score 3):

[using-tools](/questions/tagged/using-tools) would not be different from [tools](/questions/tagged/tools), which means the tag would not disallow users from asking bad questions, or off-topic questions.

You don't see much tags on Stack Exchange that contains a verb, probably because the tag is shorter, or it is preferable not to use a `<verb>ing-<object>` tag.

To make an example, on Stack Overflow there is [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode); imagine if the tag were [using-xcode](/questions/tagged/using-xcode). Would the tag limit the off-topic/bad questions?

I guess that some users who want to use [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode) would start to type xcode, and would select [using-xcode](/questions/tagged/using-xcode) because the autocomplete suggests that, without even reading in which cases the tag should be used, not even in the case the tag excerpt would suggest the question is probably going to be closed.
On Drupal Answers, we had a drupal.org tag which was used to ask questions about Drupal.org community, such as "How do I contribute a module on Drupal.org?" The tag was used from users who were not asking a question about that topic. It was used because they were asking a question about Drupal, and entered drupal when writing the tags; when the autocomplete suggested drupal.org, they selected it, uncaring of the tag excerpt saying the tag had a specific purpose.

Comment: https://i.chzbgr.com/completestore/12/8/11/8WtOr3WvOUizgKI4HVQo-Q2.jpg